Why does unity increase total allocated memory when its running idle?
I created a new empty project just to test memory leak.
This is the only script in the project:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MemoryLeakTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Tester: {UnityEngine.Profiling.Profiler.GetTotalAllocatedMemoryLong()} bytes allocated");

    }
}



The value returned by GetTotalAllocatedMemoryLong() increases in every single frame.
These are 2 values approximately 1 second away from each other:
Tester: 184550386 bytes allocated
Tester: 185042731 bytes allocated
Why does unity keep increasing allocating more memory while running idle?

Is this in the editor, or with a built project? The garbage collector runs as infrequently as possible, and 500Kb/s isn't allocating that fast, especially if this is in the editor.

Tbh, the 500Kb/s could be coming from the Debug.Log call itself, storing the message and stacktrace every frame in the console could easily add up to the 500Kb of allocations you're seeing.

It's in the editor. But would debug.log really need that much space? I mean, just to print ~100 characters, why would it need 500 k memory space? But of course, if it's going to garbage collect and reduce the size, it's not a problem. I was just worried if there was a memory leak in my build(for some bug) or if this is normal.

Debug.Log also stores the stacktrace as context, not just the message itself. An empty project can also easily get up to 200+fps, which at 500kb/s would mean ~2-3kb for each Debug.Log, stacktrace included, seems reasonable to me. This is on top of the editor process itself which might have its own allocations.

Apparently, you're right. It is caused by Debug.Log. I just editted the code to call debug.log once every second, instead of every frame. And it increased appx. same amount it does between 2 frames.

Since you said this is being done in the editor, it's just the Debug.Log storing both the message and the stacktrace as context.
185042731 bytes - 184550386 bytes = ~500kb/s
An empty project can also easily get up to 200+fps, which at 500kb/s would mean ~2-3kb for each Debug.Log, stacktrace included, seems reasonable to me. This is on top of the editor process itself which might have its own allocations.
Obviously, the GC can't garbage collect the console message until you clear them, otherwise you'll never be able to see them.

I just changed debug method to writing into a TMP_Text and memory allocation change stopped. So, it's now sure to be caused by debug.
